# Submitting a job array

Tags: parallel-processing

I am suppose to submit a job in parallel, but I am new to this and it is not really working. This is what I have until now:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                      
#PBS -q s48                                                                                                                      
#PBS -l walltime=2:00:00                                                                                                         
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1                                                                                                            
#PBS -o localhost:${PBS_O_WORKDIR}/                                                                                              
#PBS -e localhost:${PBS_O_WORKDIR}/                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
PRM=$(awk "NR==$PBS_ARRAYID {print;exit}" 89418.txt)
echo "Start"
./Hysto $PRM
echo "Done"
```

So 89418.txt is the file I read from and Hysto is the program I want to run. So I submit it using qsub -t 1-10 run.sh (run.sh is the name of the file I submit) but it is not working. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error message from the queueing system? Is Hysto called incorrectly?